# Selector [ng\:model="query"] did not match any elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, karma-runner

Why am I getting this error: `Selector [ng\:model="query"] did not match any elements`

I've read through this: [AngularJS: End to End Testing Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018597/angularjs-end-to-end-testing-issue) , but that link doesn't really apply in a .net env:

IDE: Visual Studio 2012
Project type: ASP.NET MVC4
File strucure:
[image: folder structure]

Running CI tests through karma start e2e.conf.js in node.js command prompt

My karma conf:

```
basePath = '../../../';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'angular/app/*.js',
  'angular/Tests/e2e/*.js'
];

reporters = ['progress'];

port = 10876;

runnerPort = 10100;

colors = true;

logLevel = LOG_ERROR;

autoWatch = true;

browsers = ['Firefox'];

captureTimeout = 60000;

singleRun = false;

proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:60607/'
};
```

My e2e test:

```
describe('E2E: AMS', function () {

    describe('Settings Users', function () {

        beforeEach(function () {
            browser().navigateTo('/#/settings/users');
        });


        it('filters the users list as the user types into the search box', function () {
            expect(repeater('.users li').count()).toBe(2);

            input('query').enter('abc');
            expect(repeater('.users li').count()).toBe(1);

            input('query').enter('efg');
            expect(repeater('.users li').count()).toBe(1);

            input('query').enter('ijk');
            expect(repeater('.users li').count()).toBe(0);
        });
    });
});
```

My View:

```
<div data-ng-view="">

Add User: <br />
<input type="text" /> <button>Submit</button><br />

Search:
<input data-ng-model="query" type="text" />

Users <br />
<ul class="users">
    <li data-ng-repeat="user in users | filter:query">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and for grins, my route

```
angular.module('AMS', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/login', { templateUrl: '/AccessControl/Login/', controller: settingsController }).
          when('/dashboard', { templateUrl: '/Dashboard/Dashboard', controller: dashboardController }).
          when('/settings', { templateUrl: '/Settings/Settings', controller: settingsController }).
          when('/settings/users', { templateUrl: '/Settings/Users', controller: settingsController }).
          otherwise({ redirectTo: '/dashboard' });
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the angular e2e testing api is looking for "ng-model" in your view instead of the "data-ng-model" that you're using.

My understanding is that both are valid, but give that a try to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try removing the "data-" part on the view, since I don't think I have any control over the way angular is handling the left side of the selector.

Comment: replacing data-ng-model with ng-model did not change the result of the test. Looks like something else is causing the test to fail. I should mention that the view does work as expected, its only the test that is failing.

Comment: Sorry, red herring.  It sounds like you're testing from the command line.  The e2e test might be easier to debug from a runner file like the one in angular seed: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/test/e2e/runner.html    (you can insert a pause() command in the middle of your test and then check to make sure you're in the state you expect).

Comment: I think there's a typo in the code. Changing 'ng\:model' for 'ng-model' doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, so I wont mark it as such, this is more of a work around.

I've decided to go with chutzpah in order to run the jasmine unit tests, and specflow.xunit for "e2e" testing. It works well in a .net environment and integration into teamcity seems straight forward.