# Is it necessary to have a runner.html to run an e2e test?

Tags: angularjs

Is it necessary to have a runner.html to run an e2e test?
Related to [Selector [ng\:model="query"] did not match any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531147/selector-ng-model-query-did-not-match-any-elements)

I am trying to get my e2e test running, but it keeps on failing.
The errors make it look like the test "engine" can't find any elements to assert against (see linked question).

I'm assuming that by having my karma config set up correctly, it will scan the included files specified by the karma config and run the test.
I'm assuming this because the karma runner **does** in fact detect the test, but the test itself fails.

Please see the linked question for the relevant code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runner is just a convenient way to do testing.
Karma will run headless (without a browser).